# Inheritance diagram on the XGBoost documentation

Tags: c++, doxygen, xgboost, diagram, read-the-docs

How can I view an extended inheritance diagram with more than two layers in the XGBoost documentation, specifically on the [TreeUpdater page](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dev/classxgboost_1_1TreeUpdater.html)? Currently, the diagram displayed shows only two layers of inheritance.

[image]

Is there a setting or option within the documentation that allows me to view more layers of inheritance for a more comprehensive understanding of the class hierarchy?

This is the inheritance diagram I expected (I found it in some blogs):
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The version referenced is 1.9.1 the current doxygen version is 1.9.8. The question is which doxygen versions did the blogs use and which doxygen settings did they use.